# How to handle data from form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute, spring-form

I have jsp that show all posts in blog

```
<body>
    <table>
        <c:forEach var="post" items="${posts}">
            <tr>
                <td>${post.id}</td>
                <td>${post.text}</td>
                <td><a href="authors?name=${post.author}">Show author</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

    <div>
        <a href="posts/get.json">JSON</a> <a href="posts/get.xml">XML</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

I have controller to handle it

```
@Controller
public class PostsController {

    @Autowired
    private PostDAO postDao;

    @RequestMapping("/posts")
    public String showAllPosts(ModelMap model) {

        List<Post> posts = postDao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "posts";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/posts/get")
    public List<Post> getAllPosts() {
        List<Post> posts = postDao.findAll();
        return posts;
    }

}
```

Now I want to add form to save new post.

I add form in my jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/posts/add" modelAttribute="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="id">Id:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="text">Text:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form:form>
```

Also I add to controller.

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/posts/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAdd(@ModelAttribute("post") Post post, ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("posts", postDao.addPost(post));

        return "posts";
    }
```

Domain model Post.java

```
public class Post {

    private int id;

    private String author;

    private String text;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

But I get

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'post' available as request attribute
```

Comment: When do you get this, when your request the page or when you post to the controller?

Comment: when request page /posts

Comment: Can you show us your Post.java please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your JSP contains the new form for adding a new post, it will need the model attribute `post` to be present when you go to `/posts`.

```
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public String showAllPosts(ModelMap model) {

    List<Post> posts = postDao.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("post", new Post()); // Add empty form backing object
    model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
    return "posts";
}
```

You could even split out model creation to a separate method if you find you're having to create the model in multiple places. This will ensure that its always available.

```
@ModelAttribute("post")
public Post createModel() {
    return new Post();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "createcustomer",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String customer(Model model)
    {
        Customer cus=new Customer();
        cus.setCustomerNumber("Test");
        model.addAttribute("customer",cus);
        return "createcustomer";
    }
```

In View:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %> 

<div class="cl">    
   <form:form commandName="customer" method="POST">

      <p>Name: <c:out value="${customer.CustomerNumber}"></c:out></p>

   </form:form>
<div>
```

Output:

```
Name: Test
```